# How to set value of radio button to paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a group of radio buttons and would like to change the innerHtml of a paragraph tag to the value of the selected radio button.

Currently I have the following:

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
                    <div style="height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-left: 1px solid grey; border-right: 1px solid grey">
                        <p>100kms per day@Html.RadioButton("uniqueRadio", item.standard_100, new { @checked = true })</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-left: 1px solid grey; border-right: 1px solid grey">
                        <p>200kms per day@Html.RadioButton("uniqueRadio", item.standard_200)</p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-left: 1px solid grey; border-right: 1px solid grey">
                        <p>400kms per day@Html.RadioButton("uniqueRadio", item.standard_400)</p>
                    </div>
</form>
```

The paragraph tag that I want to manipulate:

```
<p id="currentRate"></p>
```

What I am using to manipulate the paragraph tag:

```
<script>
     document.mainForm.onclick = function () {
        var radVal = document.mainForm.uniqueRadio.value;
        document.getelementById("currentRate").innerHTML = 'You selected: ' + radVal;
    }
</script>
```

I am unsure if I have an error somewhere along the line or I am approaching it in the wrong way. Please advise further.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
document.getelementById("currentRate").innerHTML = 'You selected: ' + radVal;
```

You need to capitalize the E in Element:

```
document.getElementById("currentRate").innerHTML = 'You selected: ' + radVal;
```

Comment: Stupid typo from my side but unfortunately it still does not change the value